# SQLlite3 - How do I target a specific value in SQL table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `users` with two columns containing `user_names` with type `text` with a name and `points` with the type `real`. My goal is to select a specific value of an element in the first column called lets say `user4` and return the integer that is to the right of it.

My first thought was to use something that looks like this

```
select points from users where user_name like user4
```

Should this be accomplished some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like all you're looking for here is validation. Your SQL statement as written will work fine if you simply add single quotes around `user4`. The only other thing I would change is to use `=` in place of `like`. The `like` keyword is typically only used when doing a wildcard matching which you are not doing in this case.

Comment: I get an "no such table user4" exception independent of `like/=`.

Comment: That error message doesn't look consistent with the SQL statement in your question. The SQL statement in your question selects from a table called "users".

Comment: I am sorry, I meant `no such column: user4` exception.

Comment: Also, make sure there are single quotes around 'user4' or whatever username you are searching for.

Comment: Yey, the quotes around `user4`did their thing. Thank you for your help!